# Django register user

Tags: python, django

Hi i want to connect normal user using UserCreationForm and my own Creation when i post it with button my postgre auth_user and auth_users_register nthing add to database when i click on button
my code:

**forms.py**

```
class RegisterForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Register
    fields = ['date_of_birth', 'image_add']
    widgets = {
        'date_of_birth': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'})
    }


class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

**models.py**

```
def validate_image(image_add):
    max_height = 250
    max_width = 250
    if 250 < max_width or 250 < max_height:
        raise ValidationError("Height or Width is larger than what is allowed")


class Register(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(
        max_length=8, verbose_name="date of birth")
    image_add = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="avatars", verbose_name="avatar", validators=[validate_image])
```

**views.py**

```
class RegisterPageView(View):

def get(self, request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
    user_form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
    register_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'register_form': register_form})

def post(self, request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        register_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and register_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            register_form.save(commit=False)
            user = user_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(
                request, 'Your account has been registered' + user)
            return redirect('login')

    user_form = CreateUserForm()
    register_form = RegisterForm()
    context = {'user_form': user_form, 'register_form': register_form}
    return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the user is saved ?

The register form cannot be saved in database because you set `commit=False` and never save it later.

I suggest these modifications :

```
if user_form.is_valid() and register_form.is_valid():
    user = user_form.save()
    register_form.save(commit=False)
    register_form.user = user
    register_form.save()
    messages.success(
        request, 'Your account has been registered')
    return redirect('login')
```

Comment: still dosent work ;/ register_form still bugged i change it little but i cant connect yet

Comment: ok im done it with debugger but its not clean code ;/

Comment: So what was the real problem ?

Answer (score -1):

still dosent work ;/ register_form still bugged i change it little but i cant connect yet
null value in column "user_id" of relation "auth_users_register" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (10, 2021-01-21, avatars/LOGO150x40_rzNw9bG.png, null)
i need connect  register_form user_id with id in user_form
in code :

```
def post(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            user_form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
            if user_form.is_valid():
                register_form = RegisterForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
                if register_form.is_valid():
                    user = user_form.save()
                    register_form.save(commit=False)
                    register_form.user = user
                    register_form.save()
                    user2 = register_form.cleaned_data.get('image_add')
                    messages.success(
                        request, 'Image added' + user2)
                user_form.save()
                user = user_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                messages.success(
                    request, 'Your account has been registered' + user)
                return redirect('login')
            else:
                print(user_form.errors)

        context = {'user_form': user_form, 'register_form': register_form}
        return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```

Comment: Do you have the user saved correctly after this line `user = user_form.save()`. If you can print it and maybe show its id ?

Answer (score -1):

if someone want : this connect two forms and added only images lower 250px x 250px , check logging and registers

```
class RegisterPageView(View):

def get(self, request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
    user_form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
    register_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    context = {'user_form': user_form, 'register_form': register_form}
    return render(request, 'register.html', context)

def post(self, request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        register_form = RegisterForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        image_adds = request.FILES.get('image_add')
        register_form.instance.image_add = image_adds
        height_image = register_form.instance.image_add.height
        width_image = register_form.instance.image_add.width
        if height_image < 250 and width_image < 250:
            user_form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
            if user_form.is_valid():
                user_form.save()
                user_form_id = user_form.instance.id
                register_form.instance.image_add = image_adds
                register_form.instance.user_id = user_form_id
                if register_form.is_valid():
                    register_form.save()
                user = user_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                messages.success(
                    request, 'Your account has been registered' + user)
                return redirect('login')

                context = {'user_form': user_form,
                           'register_form': register_form}
                return render(request, 'register.html', context)
        if height_image > 250 and width_image > 250:
            return redirect('register')
        else:
            print(user_form.errors)
    else:
        return redirect('register')
```